# How to add items to a stringArray in arrayList from mainActivity programatically Android

Tags: android, string

This is the array defined in strings.xml and called on MainActivity. Now I wanna add another city say city5 to this array but programmatically

```
<string-array name="city_array">
        <item> city1 </item>
        <item> city2 </item>
        <item> city3 </item>
        <item> city4 </item>
    </string-array>
```

I want to Add items Grammatically in it how? Hope anyone knows it better

Comment: pls explain your problem properly

Comment: just write your query to google. hope you will get a lot answer with awesome explanation.

Comment: I've edited my question for better understanding

Comment: @RajeshJadav now you check

Comment: @Rustam now hope it is clear for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not edit strings.xml programatically

You can get array defined in strings.xml this way:

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city_array);
```

then you can convert String array to ArrayList this way:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

then you can add extra data to your list.

```
list.add("city5");
list.add("city6");
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I understand it hope it works 
Thank you Very Much

Comment: It is not Working and didn,t add anyValue to String-array .

Comment: are you checking String array in strings.xml?

Comment: Yes i chk it as well

Comment: String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city_array);
     
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     list = Arrays.asList(array);
     ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(list);
     arrayList.add("city5");
     array = arrayList.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

Comment: You can only add data into your activity then use it in activity but you can not add programatically added data in strings.xml

Comment: Ok I got it
Well know i want 
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
          R.array.city_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
use my own simple array (String[] array = {"city1","city2","city3"};) rather then  R.array.city_array
So what i write on adapter so it get it